# Как убрать переход пробел в конце строки?

Tags: c#

В джсоне, который я парсю, в некоторых переменных встречается пробел(сложно исправить) например: {"Name":"Jon "}. Каким образом его его можно убрать потом в переменной программно?

Comment: См. `String.TrimEnd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно убрать используя `String.Replace(" ","");`
Можно использовать`String.TrimEnd(' ');` как уже сказал Yaant

Comment: Да, благодаря Yaant наткнулся на очень полезную статью работы со строками( http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.2.php ), много решений сразу придумал